# What’s the condition to form an astrophysical wormhole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, wormholes

According to GR, what’s the mechanism for a star to form a wormhole? How is it different from collapsing to a black hole? What’s the energy scale required?

Comment: A star cannot form a wormhole. It's true there is a kind of wormhole in the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates but it's not a physically realistic one.

Comment: A good source: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-to-build-a-time-machine-2006-02/

Comment: You might find this PBS Spacetime video interesting - [What if Singularities DO NOT Exist?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRir6-9tsJs)

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question.

Answer (score 1):

A [wormhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) is a purely theoretical object. Although some types of wormhole are consistent with the equations of general relativity, we have no idea how (or even if) a wormhole could form in our universe. The types of wormholes that have been examined theoretically seem to require forms of [exotic matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter), and we do not know of a mechanism for creating exotic matter, certainly not in large quantities.